# two semaphors, two functions and one function only is allowed to work at the same time

Tags: c

I have the following exercise:

> The given program snippet contains two functions mywrite() and
> myread(), which are in the same Write file or read from file. These
> two functions are used by a lot of threads called again and again. It
> should be ensured that at the same time either only read or can be
> written. Only one writing thread is permitted at a time will. Multiple
> reading threads are allowed at the same time. Complete the given
> program using only the given ones for your solution binary semaphores
> S and T, and the integer variable c. Your solution does not have to be
> fair be. For the initialization of a semaphore you can e.g. e.g. use
> S:=0, this means that the semaphore is busy. Use the functions
> introduced in the lecture: S.acquire() or S.release().

and the following solution:

```
Semaphor S := 1;
Semaphor T := 1;

int c = 0;
void mywrite()
{
    T.acquire();
    write_data_to_file();
    T.release();
}

void myread()
{
    S.acquire();
    if (c == 0)
    {
        T.acquire()
    }
    c++;
    S.release();
    read_data_from_file();
    S.acquire();
    c--;
    if (c == 0)
    {
        T.release()
    }
    S.release();
}
```

I do not know, why T.acquire() comes after S.acquire() in the myread() function.
the counter increments, but why? the mywrite() function never checks the value of c.

Comment: Re "*why T.acquire() comes after S.acquire() in the myread() function*", `S` provides mutually exclusive access to `c`.

Comment: @4386427 `T` does more than that. In addition to being used to block a writer when there's a reader, it's used to block a second writer, and it's used to block a reader when there's a writer.

Comment: @4386427, No, you made no mention of blocking readers.

Comment: @4386427, That's when *writers* are blocked. I said you made no mention of blocking *readers*.

Comment: Re "*It's pretty simple... It means that*", No, That's still wrong. A writer can't start when there's an active writer

Comment: No, it's what what you had said previously. You had made no mention of readers having to wait. That's not hair splitting. It's a crucial function.

Comment: @4386427, Done. Both descriptions are still wrong. /// The first has no mention of blocking readers. It only mentions restrictions on writing. (It strictly talks about protecting "write to file".) /// The second still doesn't mention writer can't start while there's an active writer ("a writer can't start as long as there are active readers").

Comment: @4386427, Also, `S` doesn't just prevent multiple changes from occurring at the same time. It also prevents a change from happening during a read. So the part about `S` was wrong too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`S` provides mutually exclusive access to `c`.

---

Each writer acquires and releases `T`.

`T` is also acquired by a reader when there are no other active readers. It is released when there are no more active readers.

This ensures:

- Would-be writers wait when there's an active writer.
- Would-be readers wait when there's an active writer.
- Would-be writers wait when there's one or more active readers.

`c` is the count of active readers. A reader uses `c` to determine if there are other active readers. In other words, a reader uses `c` to determine if it needs to acquire `T`, and if it should release `T`.

You can't have multiple threads accessing `c` simultaneously, so some form of mutual exclusion is needed around access of `c`. `S` is used to provide that functionality. `S` isn't acquired before `T` is acquired so much as `S` is acquired before `c` is accessed.

Comment: Thank you very much. Cannot understand exactly everything. So, 1. in the function mywrite the method write_data_to_file() it locked by the Semaphor T. So only the Semaphor T is allowed to start this function, right?

Comment: Then, in the myread() function, why then it checks two times if c == 0, when c is the number of active readers? And why do it needs also the semaphor T in this function? Is it not enough to use one Semaphor for one funtion?

Comment: `write_data_to_file()` can only be called when that thread has acquired `T`, yes.

Comment: Re "*why do it needs also the semaphor T in this function?*", To prevent would-be writers from acquiring `T`, while also causing would-be readers to wait when there's an active writer. /// Imagine if you only allowed one writer or one reader at a time. You'd use `void mywrite() { T.acquire(); write_data_to_file(); T.release(); } void myread() { T.acquire(); read_data_from_file(); T.release(); }` Allowing multiple readers at once doesn't remove the requirement that you can't have an active reader and an active writer at the time same, so the readers (as a whole) still need to acquire `T`.

Comment: But when c is the number of active readers. I understand, that when if c == 0, T kann be aquired, because there is NO active reader, right? this is the check-mechanism of c, or not? But where is the connection between c and would-be writers? c is not used by myWrite() function?

Comment: Why would `mywrite` care about the number of readers?

Comment: Ok and why the writers as a whole do not need to acquire S?

Comment: `S` provides mutually exclusive access to `c`. `mywrite` doesn't use `c`.

Comment: Ok, but when mywrite do not care about the number of readers, why then myread caer about the number of writers?

Comment: Does it? Can there even be more than one writer?

Comment: Ah now I understand: myread blocks with T.acquire the T Semaphor, so he is sure about that mywrite cannot use the Semaphor T and also cannot write data to file. Right?

Comment: yup. And vice-versa. Writers block readers.  And writers block other writers. Only because of the `if` skipping `T.acquire` do readers not block other readers.